# Keepass XC auto type often not working properly

Tags: debian, keepass, cinnamon

I am using Debian Buster and Cinnamon Desktop.

For my daily work, I use guake as a drop down console on monitor one and Konsole for my second screen. When I run, for example, mtr on guake, Keepass XC's auto type will not work on Konsole, as the focus is somehow lost between pressing the hotkey of KeePass and it starting to type. I can see that because the caret is only a frame after selecting the password from the KeePass XC popup.

The pattern for the auto type feature is simply "*Konsole".

How can I prevent this from happening? I am entering passwords about 40 to 100 times a day and this can get quite annoying. It always works when I close guake, but adds a lot more keystrokes throughout the day.